# Display active radio button bound from view model in mvc 6 with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to bind a boolean property from my view model to a set of radio button inputs and show the active button using bootstrap button groups once loaded.

[buttons example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc1J5.png)

I am able to successfully bind the value to the input using the following code:

```
`<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" asp-for="ProtectionSingleProvider" value="true"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" asp-for="ProtectionSingleProvider" value="false"> No
    </label>
</div>
`
```

When inspecting the elements once rendered, you can see that the correct radio includes the checked property however, the parent label doesn't include the 'active' css class which it requires.

I'm considering the jQuery approach where I find all checked inputs then add the 'active' css class to the parent element, but wondered if there was a better way to do this using asp.net core tag helpers.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Michael, I ended up going down the jQuery route of finding all the checked inputs and then add the active class to the parent elements.

$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});